# Problem with glut.h

Tags: c++, opengl, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT with MinGW. 
I must compile and run a c++ program with OpenGL. I have just configured the include e lib directories of MinGW and I have just runned several OpenGL programs in C with Eclipse CDT.

This time I have a problem. This program contains a glut.h file. In this file I have this section of code:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
# ifndef GLUT_BUILDING_LIB
//extern _CRTIMP void __cdecl exit(int);
_CRTIMP __declspec (noreturn) void __cdecl exit (_In_ int _Code);
# endif
...
```

If I build the project I received 2 errors:

```
..\src\glut.h:153: error: variable or field 'exit' declared void
..\src\glut.h:153: error: '_In_' was not declared in this scope
```

and I don't know why...

Comment: Which `GLUT` implementation are you using?